# Mapping a color variable in plotly bar charts

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly

I am trying to reproduce [this](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#mapping-a-color-variable) bar chart with my dataset, which is an `xts` object like this:

```
distance <- structure(c(-0.88, 2.61, 3.31, 4.7, 7.49, 0.51, 0.51, -5.07, 
0.51, -2.28, 8.89, -7.86, -10.65, -7.86, -7.86, -7.86, -7.86, 
-5.07, -3.65, -1.29, 2.96, 4.15, 6.92, -2.08, 1.05, -5.51, -0.48, 
-2.95, 4.24, -6.34, -8.73, -6.97, -1.62, -9.22, -11.66, -7.73, 
4.7, 4.7, 6.1, 8.89, 7.49, 8.89, 6.1, 0.51, 8.89, 6.1, 8.89, 
3.31, -2.28, -2.28, -2.28, -2.28, -2.28, -5.07, -29.5, -19.03, 
-10.65, -16.24, -14.84, -27.41, -16.24, -32.99, -24.61, -44.16, 
-35.78, -58.12, -52.54, -55.33, -49.74, -49.74, -55.33, -72.08, 
-16.94, -9.26, -5.07, -10.65, -7.86, -16.24, -9.26, -19.03, -16.24, 
-24.61, -30.2, -35.78, -24.61, -30.2, -38.57, -27.41, -38.57, 
-58.12, -21, -11.72, -6.77, -12.43, -10.48, -18.3, -11.61, -22.85, 
-18.07, -27.5, -26.07, -36.69, -32.35, -33.93, -35.27, -30.9, 
-35.64, -42.99), index = structure(c(1513292400, 1516316400, 
1518735600, 1521154800, 1524175200, 1529013600, 1537480800, 1545346800, 
1561068000, 1576796400, 1592517600, 1608246000, 1639695600, 1671145200, 
1702594800, 1734649200, 1766098800, 1797548400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "", .Dim = c(18L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("Call Median", "Call Mean", "Call 3rd Qu.", "Put 1st Qu.", 
    "Put Median", "Put Mean")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

So I would like to group my data like this:

- by `as.character(index(distance))` like `ggplot2::diamonds$cut` on x-axis;
- by using different colors according to `colnames(distance)` like `ggplot2::diamonds$clarity`;

My trial so far:

```
# Transpose is just because... who knows? Maybe it works
distance.t = t(distance)

as.data.frame(distance.t) %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~rownames(distance.t),
    y = ~as.data.frame(distance.t),
    type = "bar",
    color = ~colnames(distance.t))
```

Result:

```
Error: Column `color` must be length 1 or 18, not 6
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly expects that the `x` and `y` values have the same shape or have a length of 1, i.e. they all have the same coordinates.

In the example in the documentation each value has its own `x`, `y` and `color` value. Your data holds the same information but not in a way which can be understood by Plotly.

You could plot the data by iterating over it and adding the bars sequentially.

```
p <- plot_ly(x = attr(distance, "index"))
for (i in 1:dim(distance)[2])
{
  p <- add_bars(p,
                y = as.numeric(distance[,i]),
                name = colnames(distance)[i]
                )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you switch x-axis labels with colors?

Comment: Not sure If I understand the question. Do you mean having the x-axis categories as color and the labels in the legends as x-axis values?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean :)

Comment: In that case you just need to flip `x` and `name` and change the loop variable, see updated answer